# Escape sequence in terminal or iTerm to jump to absolute column?

Tags: terminal, macos, script, iterm

Is there an escape sequence which I can use to jump to an absolute column in OS X Yosemite Terminal or iTerm?

In other words:

```
echo 12345678901234567890
echo \StartAtColumn10 A10 \StartAtColumn2 B2
```

Would produce the following output:

```
12345678901234567890
 B2      A10
```

I want to send this code from R to format progress output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\r` to return to the beginning of the line (column 1) and then `\e[nC` to move right `n` characters (column n+1). So:

```
$ echo 12345678901234567890; echo $'\r\e[9CA10' $'\r\e[1CB2'
12345678901234567890
 B2      A10
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you are looking for, but I think you are looking something like `column` command. May be?

```
$ echo \A10 \B2 | column -s\ -t
A10 B2
```

For more info: `man column`.

Comment: That would surely work - but I want to send the output from R, ( `cat()` function). So I can not use a second command like `column`.